# How can I do to my spring boot resource server oauth 2 get user's extra data from api when user authenticate e keep it into security context?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, security-context

I have a resource server done with Spring Boot. I'm using Spring Security 5.3 to authenticate and authorize the frontend exchange data. I've configured a authorization server "issuer-uri" in application.yml that provides and validates the access_token (jwt).

Until there ok. The problem that authorization server doesn't provide at once every user's information that I need in access_token or id_token. With the sub claim and access_token I need to do a request to endpoint to get more extra data about user.

I would like to know how can I do a request to get that information just when the user authenticates and put them into security context togheter the information that's already comes. So that way, I could get that information in some service when needed without make a request to endpoint each time:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()
```

It's here my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String CLAIM_ROLES = "role";
  private static final String AUTHORITY_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
  @Value("${sso.issuers_uri}")
  private String issuers;

  Map<String, AuthenticationManager> authenticationManagers = new HashMap<>();

  JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver =
        new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagers::get);


  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String[] result = issuers.split(",");
    List<String> arrIssuers = Arrays.asList(result);

    arrIssuers.stream().forEach(issuer -> addManager(authenticationManagers, issuer));

    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/*",
                            "/signin-oidc",
                            "/uri-login_unico",
                            "/assets/**","/views/**",
                            "index.html",
                            "/api/segmentos/listar_publicados",
                            "/api/modelos",
                            "/api/modelos/*"
                    ).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/api/admin/**"
                    ).hasRole("role.PGR.Admin")
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/api/govbr/**"
                    ).hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_govbr_empresa")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> {
                oauth2ResourceServer.authenticationManagerResolver(this.authenticationManagerResolver);
            });
  }

  public void addManager(Map<String, AuthenticationManager> authenticationManagers, String issuer) {
    JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer));
    authenticationProvider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());
    authenticationManagers.put(issuer, authenticationProvider::authenticate);
  }

  private Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> getJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    
  jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(getJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
  }

  private Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> getJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter converter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    converter.setAuthorityPrefix(AUTHORITY_PREFIX);
    converter.setAuthoritiesClaimName(CLAIM_ROLES);
    return converter;
  }

}
```

I don't know if I need to do a custom AuthenticationManger or if I can do this with a security filter after authenticated. If someone could help me, I really apprecite it. Tks!!!